# Remove a:hover in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, removeclass

I have the following javascript code:

```
$('#s2 a').click(function(){
    var cB = $(this);
    var f = parseInt(cB.attr('data-f'));
    var r = parseInt(cB.attr('data-r'));
    var c = parseInt(cB.attr('data-c'));
    if (pA == false && !isClickAllowed(f,r,c)) {
        return false;
    }
    // more stuff comes here 
}
```

This makes a link not clickable. This all works. I also want to remove the hover effect. The CSS code for this is:

```
.pc a:hover {
    background-color: #FFF;
```

I thought removing the class would do it like: `cB.removeClass('pc');` but this doesn't work.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Thank you for your time

--EDIT--

Hmm I think I see why it aint working. At the top of the document I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setScale();
    $(window).resize(setScale);
    if (!('ontouchstart' in document)) {
        $('body').addClass('pc');
    } 
        more code here
```

This sets the `.pc a:hover` for all links when opened the page on a pc rather then a touch device (e.g. iPad). I need to disable this pc hover ONLY on the links are not clickable like in:

```
if (pA == false && !isClickAllowed(f,r,c)) {
        return false;
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm intrigued - why do you want a link that people can't click on? If it's just a style thing, would it not be easier to create a 'fakelink' class that is blue and underlined?

Comment: Oh, and you usually want to avoid writing `== false`. May I suggest `if(!pa && !isClickAllowed(f, r, c))`?

Comment: Thanks @minitech I'll use that one

Answer (score 6):

cB is the anchor which isn't being references by the CSS class you indicate, the parent would have the class `pc` for this to work. `cB.parent().removeClass('pc');` would do it.

-- EDIT --

Following the erudite comments below it would seem that `cb.parents('.pc').removeClass('pc')` or `cb.parents().removeClass('pc')` (I've not benchmarked to see which is quicker) would be the comprehensive solution.

Good catch to James, Anthony, and Tadeck!

-- EDIT 2 --

Following the question update, I'd suggest adding another class to your links, i.e. `clickable`, then your CSS becomes:

```
.pc a.clickable:hover {
    background-color: #FFF;
```

and you can just remove the `clickable` class on those links that you don't want to show the highlight. The better course of action may be to simply replace the links that are disabled with either raw text or as spans with an identifying class, i.e. `disabled_link` if you want to have the option to enable them later.

Comment: This assumes that the direct parent has the class of `pc`.  Based on the css, it could be any ancestor, in which case you could use `closest`.

Comment: `.pc a:hover` references any hovered anchors that are contained within an element that has the class `pc`, not just ones that are the immediate child of an element that has the class `pc`, so the code in your answer may not necessarily work depending on the HTML.

Comment: @JamesMontagne: Partially correct - the `closest()` will not make it, if there are multiple parents with `pc` class. Both of these should do the trick: `cB.parents().removeClass('pc');` or, probably more efficiently `cB.parents('.pc').removeClass('pc');`.

Comment: James, Anthony, Tadeck: You are correct, I made an assumption I shouldn't have. Good catch!

Comment: Hi all, first let me thank you for all the replies. I am starting to think I am implementing this wrong into my code. Can some one give me a code suggestion of how and where to implement these suggested changes? (cause the code still had no luck) Thanks

Comment: EDITED my question, hope this helps solving my issue

Comment: Thanks for your edit, unfortunately it had no luck. I also have an: `function isClickAllowed`, but adding it in there brakes the script. Unfortunately that code is too big to post here. How can I post bigger chunks of code?

Comment: @Maurice To be honest, any function you have that's too big to post needs refactoring as it's going to be too big to maintain as well. If you function breaks the script then you need to resolve that through console, etc. in Chrome or Firefox (Firebug), then you can look this additional problem.

Answer (score 3):

Though there was no HTML provided, based on the code, `cB` does not appear to be the element which has the class of `pc` but rather an ancestor of `cB`. You would need to remove the class from that.

If the direct parent is the only ancestor with the class of `pc`, you can do the following:

```
cB.parent().removeClass("pc")
```

If only one ancestor other than the direct parent has the class of `pc` and the parent does not, you can do the following:

```
cB.closest(".pc").removeClass("pc")
```

If multiple ancestors have the `pc` class, you can use the following:

```
cB.parents(".pc").removeClass("pc")
```

And finally, if multiple `a` tags exist within `.pc` then you cannot use the approach of removing the class, as this will affect all `a` tags within that `.pc`.

Comment: Assuming, of course, that there's only one element in the hierarchy above the anchor that has the class.

Comment: Yeah, you might try `.parents()` instead.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist right, without the HTML it's impossible to know, but if `.cp` is a container holding many links another approach would be needed.

Comment: @minitech also true. If there are multiple ancestors with the class of `cp`, `parents` would allow you to remove the class from all of them.

Comment: See my comment to @Lazarus's answer - the `closest()` will not work, if more than one parent of `cB` has `pc` class assigned.

Comment: Just if we're all being extra-sure :) And @Tadeck: See comment #1.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: You managed to reply to that comment in the half a second it existed :) Edit: Oh, the irony.

Comment: @minitech Yeah, then I noticed you'd changed it! Oh well, seems like we're all on the same page now.

Comment: @minitech: Yes, it all happened so fast, many people noticed it may not work in some cases ;)

Comment: I went ahead and updated the answer addressing all of the comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id="example">This is an example.</p> 

<script>
  document.getElementById('example').style.borderWidth = '4px';
</script>
```

Note that borderWidth is different than border-width. This can be used for the other styles. As a rule of thumb, take away the dash and make the first letter of the second word capital. If it doesn't work, Google it.

Comment: Please don't just post links; they can become dead quickly. Just include a quick summary in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

cB.removeClass('pc') should indeed remove aclass. Make sure your css behaves correctly in all scenarios. Also try targeting the parent

Comment: Please post a comment if you're "just checking".

Answer (score 0):

I would add a `disabled` class to the CSS that comes after the `:hover` rule and overrides it with the disabled styles, which may or may not be the default. Then, you can just do:

```
cB.addClass('disabled');
```

The reason your existing solution doesn't work is because you're removing the class from the element when its parent has the class.

Answer (score 0):

Since your CSS issue was already solved, I want to point out another improvement:
I see that you are using cB.attr('data-f') to store some data, but attr should only be used for valid HTML attributes.  You should consider using the jQuery data method which was created just for the purpose of storing non-attribute data into an element.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: This kind of thing is best left as a comment as it's not an answer to the question. (I realize you don't have the privileges to comment yet, but still something to keep in mind.)